# How do you send raw headers in ruby

Tags: ruby, http-headers, content-type

I have a page which uses the UTF-8 character set, however the characters are mangled on the page, I think this is just a matter of setting a header "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" ... I know how to do this in PHP, simply place the following at the top of the page.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>
```

Is there a way to do this in ruby? Can you place a header at the top of a page, like that?

---

**update:** Jun 29, 1:20p PST

I'm **not** using this as part of a rails application. It is for an embedded browser page in a stand-alone application, I can use Javascript and/or Ruby to create dynamic pages.

Comment: Please explain how you are generating the web page. Are you using the cgi module? Is it part of a Rails application?

Comment: Sorry, we can't help you. Would you post a piece of code so we can see how the content is being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails, you want:

```
response.content_type = Mime::HTML
response.charset      = "utf-8"
```

You could also try to set the headers directly:

```
response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

If you're using Rack, you want to set the header using the second element of the tuple:

```
class MyRackApp
  def call(env)
    response = []
    # do stuff with env, populating response
    # response is [status_code, headers, body]
    response[1]["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    response
  end
end
```

If you're using raw CGI (I would definitely recommend Rack over cgi.rb):

```
header("text/html; charset=utf-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the three views. I used the "cgi" library. (It was quick-n-dirty)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Ruby on Rails?

```
request.headers["Content-Type"] # => "text/plain"
```

Or maybe Ruby's CGI library?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000098

Comment: Wanna use Ruby's CGI...does ruby come with this off the shelf, or do i need to download something?

Comment: It comes with ruby, but you need to `require` it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to answer this directly without learning more about how you're generating the page, but I might suggest you look into some of the lightweight non-Rails web frameworks for Ruby. There are many and they make things like this easy.

For example, [Rack](http://vision-media.ca/resources/ruby/ruby-rack-middleware-tutorial) has an easy-to-use hash for Headers to send to the browser. Likewise in [Camping](http://camping.rubyforge.org/files/README.html) you can just do something like `@headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/css'`